# exclude directory from find command

Tags: find

I'm trying to get the hang of excluding a directory while searching for a particular file.

I'm on WSL2 so want to exclude the /mnt/ folder so I don't end up searching my entire file-system.

I can do:

```
find . -path './mnt' -prune -o -print
```

which prints all directories and files EXCLUDING the /mnt/ folder, but I'm struggling to combine this with the correct syntax to find a specific file, e.g.

```
find -name example.txt
```

Answer (score 5):

```
find . -path ./mnt -prune -o -name example.txt -print
```

Which is short for:

```
find . '(' -path ./mnt -a -prune ')' -o '(' -name example.txt -a -print ')'
```

AND (`-a`, implied when omitted) has higher precedence than OR (`-o`) as in [many other languages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_of_operations#Programming_languages).

Alternatively:

```
find . ! '(' -path ./mnt -prune ')' -name example.txt
```

Which is short for:

```
find . '(' ! '(' -path ./mnt -a -prune ')' -a -name example.txt ')' -a -print
```

The default `-print` action is added automatically this time because there's no *action* predicate otherwise in the expression.